# special character in url routing in asp.net 4.0 web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

How to handle special character in url while using url routing in asp.net 4.0?

special character like ( & , .)

It shows error as  bad request or dangerous character in url.

How to handle?

suppose i have url routing in Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomRouteTable(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
void CustomRouteTable(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Product", "Product/{pId}/{ProductName}", "~/Product/ProductDetail.aspx");

    }
```

suppose productName is  Phone&Cordless  or Phone:Cordless
then i get error.

How to handle?

Answer (score 1):

You should really just stay away from using ampersands in URLs that aren't for handling query string parameters. Consider using "-and-" instead in your product names for your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

URL has a special kind of **encoding** which is called **URL Encoding** and almost every web programming language (including JavaScript) has a way to encode and decode strings into and out from URL encodes strings. As @rkaregaran said, I also strongly recommend that you use `-` (dash) or `_` (underscore) in URLs.

Anyway, as much as I see in your explanation, I think you should use `/phone/cordless` instead of `phone:cordless`. Seems that `phone` here is a kind of taxonomy.

Comment: i can't parase the query string in /phone/Cordless. what if i endup with parameter as cordless(p). then url wil /Product/1/Cordless(p).

Comment: I have foune one url http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls. Will it be ok to use the method described?